# Is a Keras base model preprocessing layer used during model prediction?

Tags: keras, transfer-learning

My concern stems from how I currently have a preprocessing layer required for altering the input to the transfer learning base model, but I want to add several other preprocessing layers for data augmentation.

I want the base model preprocessing layer to apply to test data during predict() calls, but don't want the layers added for data augmentation to do so. According to the Keras documentation, "Data augmentation is inactive at test time so input images will only be augmented during calls to Model.fit (not Model.evaluate or Model.predict).", but is that the same for a base model preprocessing layer too?

Model Construction:

```
# layer construction
input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(targetWidth, targetHeight, 3))
preprocc_input = applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input

base_model = applications.InceptionV3(
    input_shape=(targetWidth, targetHeight, 3),
    include_top=False,
)
base_model.trainable = False

global_avg_pool_layer = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
fc_layer = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')
#dropout_layer = layers.Dropout(0.2)
output_layer = layers.Dense(
    units=1,
    activation=keras.activations.sigmoid #'softmax'
)

#layer connecting
x = preprocc_input(input_layer)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = global_avg_pool_layer(x)
x = fc_layer(x)
#x = dropout_layer(x)
predictions = output_layer(x)
model = keras.Model(input_layer, predictions)
```

Comment: what preprocessing layers are you talking about? preprocc_input? That is not a layer.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes, well regardless, is it used during both training and inference?